# How get an iBeacon his Coordinates?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gps, coordinates, ibeacon

How do you get an `iBeacon` Chip coordinates? Via GPS?
The `iBeacon` isn't connect to the Internet, right?

If an App searches `iBeacon`s nearby, you can see how far they are.

Comment: iBeacons don't have coordinates. It's a proximity technology rather than a positioning technology. iBeacons are based on Bluetooth 4.0 (Bluetooth Low Energy) and that's what determines their range—about 10m/30 feet.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if there is an cheap microcontroller available with this technology ? round about 20$ ?

Comment: There's [BLEduino](http://bleduino.cc) (pre-order only at the moment), but any Arduino with a BLE shield or Raspberry Pi with a BLE dongle will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done by searching the iBeacon Id in a database via an  internet connection, provided by the institution that installs the iBeacon.

The iBeacon itself does not have the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use the Major and Minor ID to hardcode the GPS Coordinates into the iBeacon. But as they are only 2 Bytes each this wouldn't be very precise.